# Where are all the secret music disk located?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I know  the cobble cross, tower, underground chamber, underwater dome, house by the lake, treehouse, and desert temple. (TU11)

Comment: Asker: I misclicked. Please fill in [this form](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/other) to get your account back.

Comment: Is this Minecraft for Xbox? I'm pretty sure that's an entirely different animal than Minecraft for PC as far as Music Discs go (and pretty much everything else too).

Comment: @badp Bad Mod! BAD MOD! No cookie!

Comment: @badp You just banned a random user......?

Comment: Lol badp amazing.

Answer (score 8):

Here are the locations of all of the music discs hidden throughout the tutorial world in Minecraft for Xbox, according to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Xbox_360_Tutorial_Mode#Music_Disc_Locations_.281.3-1.3.1.29):

> 1. Where Are We Now? - (X: 373 Y: 65 Z: -146) On an island On the east border of the map. [Also contains Pickaxe].
> 2. Strad - (X: 28 Y: 61 Z: 9) Is in a cave underground with pillars up on top . [Also contains Iron Axe with Fortune III].
> 3. Cat - (X: -42 Y: 57 Z: 249) In the swamp cabin to the left of the mansion. [Also contains Iron Boots with Feather Falling IV].
> 4. 11 - (X: 63 Y: 93 Z: 166) On top of the glass of the mansion. [Also contains Bow with Power V].
> 5. 13 - (X: 107 Y: 75 Z: 165) In the tunnel exiting the tutorial area. [Also contains Jukebox, Bow with Flame I, and 20 Arrows].
> 6. Ward - (X: 197 Y: 78 Z: 71) Behind tutorial area, on top of the tower. [Also contains Iron Pickaxe with Unbreaking III].
> 7. Chirp - (X: 42 Y: 77 Z: 153) Behind the lava-fall in the mansion brewing room. [Also contains Iron Chestplate with Fire Protection V].
> 8. Mellohi - (X: 86 Y: 75 Z: 166)under the cobblestone cross in the middle of the stone slabs[also contains iron sword with smite v]
> 9. Mall - (X: 102 Y: 60 Z: 268) To the left of the mansion, take the minecart to the sand temple. [Stepping on the pressure plate gives
>    Iron Sword with Looting III from a dispenser].
> 10. Blocks - (X: 65 Y: 71 Z: 176) Basement of the mansion . [Also contains Iron Helmet with Respiration III].
> 11. Far - (X: -41 Y: 59 Z: 93) In the glass building under the water. [Also contains Iron Shovel with Efficiency V].
> 12. Stal - (X: 60 Y: 61 Z: 27) This disc is the only one located in the Nether. It can be found in a humongous Nether Fortress. next to a
>     blaze spawner [Also contains Flint and Steel and enchanted Iron
>     Leggings].

Comment: Your wrong on the location on "where are we now" it's
X:208, Y:72, Z:92 in a small, old abandoned looking house with a mossy cobblestone fence, just letting you know

Comment: Yeah this appears to have changed, or might be dependent on other factors now. I'll review and revise this tomorrow.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Music_Discs#Acquiring_discs):

> The music discs "13" and "cat" are found in 8% of dungeon chests. All music discs can be obtained by getting a creeper to be killed by a skeleton's arrow.

To find the discs either go raiding dungeons or get a skeleton to shoot a creeper. To do that go up to a skeleton and wait for him to acquire you (start attacking) then find a creeper and try to get the skeleton to shoot it.

Answer (score -1):

Wait for a skeleton to come by you. Make him follow you until you find a creeper. Then get behind the creeper and get the skeleton to shoot the creeper enough that he won't explode. Before you do this get armor on.

Comment: Sorry, wrong game.